# Mootools inject code Revise it for .each

Tags: mootools, selector, inject

I have following html.

```
<ul>
<li>
    <label id="firstswitch-lbl" class="hasTip">My First Selector:</label>
    <select id="first_switch" class="switch">
        <option value="0">Enable</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="1">Disable</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <label id="first_title-lbl" class="hasTip">First Select:</label>
    <input id="first_title" class="text" type="text" size="3" value="50">
</li>
<li>
    <label id="secondswitch-lbl" class="hasTip">My Second Selector </label>
    <select id="second_switch" class="switch">
        <option value="0">Enable</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="1">Disable</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <label id="second_title-lbl" class="hasTip">Second Select:</label>
    <input id="second_title" class="text" type="text" size="3" value="100">
</li>
<li>
    <label id="thirdswitch-lbl" class="hasTip">My Third Selector </label>
    <select id="third_switch" class="switch">
        <option value="0">Enable</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="1">Disable</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <label id="third_title-lbl" class="hasTip">Third Select:</label>
    <input id="third_title" class="text" type="text" size="3" value="200">
</li>
<li>
    <label id="fourthswitch-lbl" class="hasTip">My Fourth Selector </label>
    <select id="fourth_switch" class="switch">
        <option value="0">Enable</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="1">Disable</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <label id="fourth_title-lbl" class="hasTip">Fourth Select:</label>
    <input id="fourth_title" class="text" type="text" size="3" value="200">
</li>
```

And following mootools javascript which works fine.

```
    document.id('first_switch').inject(document.id('first_switch').getParent().getNext(), 'bottom');
document.id('first_title').getParent().getPrevious().dispose();
document.id('second_switch').inject(document.id('second_switch').getParent().getNext(), 'bottom');
document.id('second_title').getParent().getPrevious().dispose();
```

However I am trying to reduce the number of time I repeat the same code as I have about 20 or more similar lines so I am looking to make it shorter or more simplified such using .each function but just cant figure it out.

I am trying to add the value box next to Selector so they are on the same line rather then using two lines. Any help highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Following is a link to Fiddle [Example Code](http://jsfiddle.net/GzVca/)

Answer (score 0):

you should tweak it a bit but:

```
document.getElements("li input.text").each(function(input) {
    var parent = input.getParent("li");
    input.inject(parent.getPrevious().getFirst(), "after");
    parent.destroy();
});
```

this will loop your whole page so i'd recommend `document.id("ulel").getElements`

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/GzVca/1/